# Vuze can't access Windows file systems

Tags: permissions, mount, vuze

My Vuze application can't store the torrent data on any Windows file systems.

I came to know that the user of Vuze is normal user, not root.

I've already tried `-o allow_other` when mounting windows file system.

Also `chmod g+rw` on  "/media/user/Drives"
Vuze can only access "/home" and subfolders and nothing other in "/ "

[Error showing when I clicked on where to save option and selected /media/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MLCv.png)

Comment: How was Vuze installed? Was it a Snap application?

Comment: Yes... It's a snap application

Comment: Snap apps use fixed directories as part of their config. Typically only the home directory of the  user that installed it.